# Socket ping error using the ws library (nodejs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, ws

I've successfully implementented the ws package for nodejs to set up a websocket server.

Everythings work fine except when I try to check the socket availability as per :

https://github.com/websockets/ws#how-to-detect-and-close-broken-connections

The `ws.ping(noop)` method always results in the following error :

```
Error: Parse Error
      at socketOnData (_http_server.js:480:20)
      at Socket.emit (events.js:187:15)
      at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:441:20)
      at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:283:12)
      at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:264:11)
      at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:219:10)
      at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:17)
```

I've tried almost everything using `ws.ping()`, `ws.ping('')` or even `ws.ping(Buffer.alloc(0))`, to no avail.

The ws socket is clean and running, I can send and retrieve data through it using events and `ws.send()` method. Only ping/pong fails. I'm using native WebSocket object on client (browser).

Is it possible that it could be related to the fact that I'm using `noServer: true` when I instantiate the websocket wss server ?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Could you please share the server code where you ping the WebSocket clients?

Comment: I realize I never replied to this but I ended up refactoring everything and it worked. The problem was actually related to Koa.js (which I was using as web framework).